# Ruby on rails - Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick / CarrierWave Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, uploader

This is the message that I get when I try to upload something that is not an image for example an mp3.

> Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image?
>   Original Error: MiniMagick::Invalid

So I tried to put a condition by checking the file extension. Only resize if It's not an mp3.

Here is my FileUploader using CarrierWave:

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

...

if File.extname(File.name) != ".mp3"
   process :resize_to_fit => [100, 100]

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [80, 80]
  end

end


...

end
```

File.name provide me only the name without the extension of the current file. Do you know the variable which provide me the name + the extension ?

EDIT:

I have found an alternative in my controller:

```
 def create
    @myfile = File.new(params[:icon])

    if @myfile.save

        if @myfile.file.file.extension != "mp3"
          @myfile.file.resize_to_fit(100, 100)

          @file.save
        end
     end
```

But now I'm stuck with on my CarrierWave FileUploader:

```
version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [80, 80]
  end
```

It's getting too complicated, I need MiniMagick only for images

I just need a small condition:

if file_is_image? ==> resize + create a thumbnail

else ==> do nothing

thanks

Comment: Just a note: why do you have both minimagick and rmagick included?

Comment: I actually use only MiniMagick It's just a mistake thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
process :resize_to_fit => [100, 100]; :if => :processable?

def processable? upload_name
  File.extname(upload_name.path) != ".mp3"
end
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `filename'.  File.name provide me only the name without the extension of the current file. Do you know the variable which provide me the name + the extension ? thanks

Comment: try to acces it via `model.file.name`

Comment: mmm... where is your code? because `model` should be valid see doc: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave

Comment: my code is in class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

Comment: from the doc: `The model variable points to the instance object the uploader is attached to.`